# Connecting an electret headset with laptop

Tags: electret, trrs

I am looking into buying a [SmartBoom PRO Dual-Ear Electret Headset Unterminated](https://plianttechnologies.com/product/smartboom-pro-dual-ear-electret-headset-unterminated/) to connect to my laptop. I work in a very noisy environment and no other microphone seems to work. The following is the wire color and description:

[image]

I am wondering if it would be possible to connect it to my laptop using a 3.5 mm 4-pole TRRS male plug connector.

Comment: There is. But why not buy the other model with dual 3.5mm plugs and a standard TRRS to dual 3.5mm adapter?

Comment: @Justme . Yes but since I don't know about connectors which adapter would work to convert dual TRRS to single TRRS?

Comment: Would this work: https://www.amazon.com/MillSO-Headset-Splitter-TRRS-Headphones/dp/B07569QKQQ?th=1

Comment: @Justme I don't think an adapter would work because, for example, they connect the Mic+ in the left T of the Dual Mini, and usually the Mic+ goes in S for CTIA standard. Am I correct?